# prevent call stack to be outputted

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to prevent call stack to be outputted when error occurred. So for example suppose:

```
 set error [catch { [exec $interpName $tmpFileName] } err]
  if { $error ne 0 } {
  puts "err = $err" #<---- Here call stack is also outputted
}
```

So output now looks like:

```
error: some error message

while executing
[stack trace]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl automatically builds up the call stack in the global variable `errorInfo` (and, since 8.5, in the `-errorinfo` member of the interpreter result options dictionary) but it is up to the calling code to decide what to do with it. The default behavior of `tclsh` is to print it out; other Tcl-hosting environments can do different things (it's usually *recommended* to print it out as it helps hunt down bugs; on the other hand, some programs — specifically Eggdrop — don't and it's a cause of much trouble when debugging scripts).

You take control of this for yourself by using `catch` in the script that's getting the original error. The easiest way to do this is to put the real code in a procedure (e.g., called `main` by analogy with C and C++) and then to use a little bit of driver code around the outside:

```
if {[catch {eval main $argv} msg]} {
    puts "ERROR: $msg"
    # What you're not doing at this point is:
    #    puts $errorInfo
    exit 1
} else {
    # Non-error case; adjust to taste
    puts "OK: $msg"
    exit 0
}
```

Note that in your code, this would go *inside the script you write to `$tmpFileName`* and not in the outer driver code that you showed (which is absolutely fine and needs no adjustment that I can think of).